# Why I don't get EnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables

Using System / System Properties / Environment Variables I set a new variable on my Windows like described here: [on youtube](https://youtu.be/bEroNNzqlF4). I create a console application like described here: [at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_) and can reach the previous set environment variable. That was just a test to use it at my grown up application. There I wrote the same line than in my test application main first line:

```
string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVariable");
```

and **the returned value is null**.
The only difference I could imagen that could play a role is that at the project properties / Debug is set already a (other) variable.

**Do you have a idea why I can't reach my EnvironmentVariable MyVariable from my main application?** What could I check for debugging?

I I set my variable via code at my main application

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(key, value);
```

than next time I start the variable is available. But actualy that is not the way I want to write the environment variables.

Comment: How are you running the code? If it's in VS, did you restart VS after setting the environment variable? If it's from the console, did you start a new console after setting the environment variable?

Comment: Type `SET` into the same DOS prompt you started your console app from; this are the variables your app will be able to retrieve. Bear in mind (implied in JonSkeet's conmen) that environment variables are effectively cloned from the existing system set when an app is started. You can create new ones and set them in the environment but they don't update the original repository. Try it yourself: open two dos windows, type `set a=b` in one and type `set a=c` in the other. Then type set in each; they maintain their own cars and you cannot influence the vars in one dos window from the other

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried restart now and there is no difference. Works at my test application and not at my main application.

Comment: @CaiusJard: it's called a `Command prompt` these day's ;-)

Comment: @CaiusJard I start my app via Visual Studio F5. So where to write "SET"?

Comment: Try setting it in code before you retrieve it. 
public static void SetEnvironmentVariable(string variable, string value);

Comment: @frankmehlhop in your solution explorer right click the bin folder, choose *open folder in file explorer*, copy the address/path out of the address box, click start, type CMD, press return, type CD then right click your mouse and paste the path, press return. Now type SET; those are the env vars your program will see. Now run your program by typing its name in the cmd window and note it can access the same vars. if you can't see it in the SET list then it will return null if you try and fetch it in code. Note also that users can have their own env vars; if your VS is running the program as..

Comment: ..a different user to what you're running CMD as then the list of vars may be different

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried C:\...\bin>SET MyVar=33, but Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyVar") is null again.

Comment: We need more information about your main application, basically. Otherwise we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say what's going on based on this information.

But I'm guessing (based on the YouTube video you mentioned) that you created a environment variable for your %USER% in Windows and running Visual Studio as another user (i.e. Administrator).

From the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_):

> On Windows systems, the environment block of the current process includes:
>
> All environment variables that are provided to it by the parent process that created it. For example, a .NET application launched from a console window inherits all of the console window's environment variables.
>
> If there is no parent process, per-machine and per-user environment variables are used instead. For example, a new console window has all per-machine and per-user environment variables defined at the time it was launched.

Try adding the environment variable as system variable and try again.

Comment: I really doubt on what base you are guessing this, and since SO is not a guessing game, this doesn't seem relevant to me at this time. Voting to close this question is.

Comment: If you look at the YouTube video you see that the variable is added as user variable instead of system variable. And Frank Mehlhop mentioned that he added the variable like in the YouTube video.

Comment: I got it! I have to set the variables as system variables and than restart visual studio. It's working now. Thank you very much for all you help!!! :-)